# Selenium click on already known element stored in variable

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm use Scrapy and Selenium. After scrapy do some work I have click-able element stored in variable so I think that `driver.find_element_by` is not necessary because element is already known. So I was hope that something like this exist:

```
my_variable = '<input type="submit" value="...">'
button = driver.element(my_variable)
button.click()
```

But `'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'element'` So it there a way to use variable instead `find_element_by`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Scrapy, but the `click()` function is `WebElement` functionality. `driver.find_element_by` returns `WebElement`, so you can do something like that:

```
WebElement button = driver.find_element_by()
button.click()
```

So in your case you can do

```
my_variable.click()
```